# Error while creating a report in wso2 bam

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I get the following message while creating a table report in wso2 bam 2.3.0 server:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Table Report is not a valide template
```

*Table Report* is the report's name that I typed. Here is a part of the stack trace:

type Exception report

```
message org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Table Report is not a valide template
```

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Table Report is not a valide template
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:61)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
root cause

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Table Report is not a valide template
    org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:93)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    org.wso2.carbon.reporting.template.stub.ReportTemplateAdminStub.addNewTableReport(ReportTemplateAdminStub.java:3183)
    org.wso2.carbon.reporting.template.ui.client.ReportTemplateClient.addNewReport(ReportTemplateClient.java:129)
    org.wso2.carbon.reporting.template.ui.upload.reportUploadExecutor.handleTableReport(reportUploadExecutor.java:85)
    org.wso2.carbon.reporting.template.ui.upload.reportUploadExecutor.execute(reportUploadExecutor.java:65)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.AbstractFileUploadExecutor.executeGeneric(AbstractFileUploadExecutor.java:104)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$CarbonXmlFileUploadExecHandler.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:392)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$FileUploadExecutionHandlerManager.startExec(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:276)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:125)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
```

Here is the full stack trace from the log file http://pastebin.com/X3WEw4GV

Answer (score 0):

Seems your jrxml template is not valid. Please recheck the tags.